# Problems Deploying .war file and Tomcat 7 (JBoss EWS 2.0)

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, tomcat7, openshift

my problem is with **openshift** because locally my web service works fine but after i push the .war file to the repo and i try to do a request to the method that i tested locally on openshift i get 404 message, it's like a dilemma i don't understand this.

I'm using tomcat 7.0.75 local with netbeans 8.2
and  Tomcat 7 (JBoss EWS 2.0) on openshift

Firstly i built a .war file with tomcat 8 and u think that the problem could be the deferents versions and then i created a .war with tomcat 7 but the same

Comment: i downloaded openshift plugin in Eclipse. And then I use that to create a new project. Then everything works fine for me

Comment: Do you use minishift locally or OpenShift NextGen? How do you deploy the war file to Tomcat in OpenShift? Is there some error message in the pod logs?

Comment: @bibix I use the first generation and for deploy my .war file on openshift I clone the repository then I add the .war file and i push the changes to the repo on openshift , openshift deploy my .war when I push the commit